# show last updated activity after leaving current activity in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm using an editing tool with ArcGIS maps.First i launch my MainActivity and there user may draw some drawings on the map.And another drawing wants to do from the list menu in material design navigation drawer, there's an item called file browser.Here after clicked that item it goes to another activity called file browser.after selecting relevant file from there i want to launch MainActivity with the edited drawings.
In my MainActivity;

```html
 public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
       switch (position) {
            case 1: {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, filechooser.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            }

            default:
                break;

        }
}
```

In FileChooser activity;

```html
//Here selecting relevent file for the drawings.Really here selecting file which contains relevent coordinates for drawings on the map and pass the file path to MainActivity.Map is on the MainActivity.This activity contains only a file browser.
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Option o = adapter.getItem(position);


        if (o.getdata().equalsIgnoreCase("folder") ||           o.getdata().equalsIgnoreCase("Parent Directory")) {
            direction = new File(o.getPath());
            fill(direction);
        } else {
            filepath = o.getPath();
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(filechooser.this, MainActivity.class);
            //but here i want to go to MainActivity with previous drawings not just to want restart activity.
            intent2.putExtra("path", filepath);
            startActivity(intent2);
            
        }
    }
```

So can i do that? If so please help me.Sory for my Engish :(

Comment: Remove the call to `onPause()` in `onNavigationDrawerItemSelected()`. These methods should only be called by the framework, never directly by your own code.

Comment: What exactly is your question? What is the problem? What is not working the way you expect?

Comment: In first activity user can add some graphics on the map.If user goes to second activity and select some thing(in my question user wants to select relevent file and want to pass file path) and then redirect to previous map activity.But the activity should saved all the things i did on the map before launch 2nd activity. But from above code when i redirect to map activity from 2nd activity, the map activity is restarted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MainActivity` should start `FileChooser` using `startActivityForResult()`. `FileChooser` then creates an `Intent` that it uses to return data to `MainActivity`. To pass this data back to `MainActivity`, `FileChooser` just needs to call `setResult()` and then `finish()` (instead of calling `startActivity()`). This will close `FileChooser` and call `onActivityResult()` in `MainActivity`.

---

**EDIT add code example**

In `MainActivity`:

```
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
   switch (position) {
        case 1: {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, filechooser.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            break;
        }
    }
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // "data" is the Intent that filechooser sent back
            // you can now do data.getStringExtra(...) or whatever to
            // get the data
            String filepath = data.getStringExtra("path");
        } else {
            // filechooser failed for whatever reason
        }
    }
}
```

In `filechooser`:

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        Option o = adapter.getItem(position);
        if (o.getdata().equalsIgnoreCase("folder") ||           o.getdata().equalsIgnoreCase("Parent Directory")) {
            direction = new File(o.getPath());
            fill(direction);
        } else {
            filepath = o.getPath();
            Intent intent2 = new Intent();
            //but here i want to go to MainActivity with previous drawings not just to want restart activity.
            // return filepath
            intent2.putExtra("path", filepath);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent2);
            // close this activity return to MainActivity
            finish();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain little bit more